# Translate how to make a dynamic JSON entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I init the first time my $translateProvider as this:

```
app.config(["$translateProvider", function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', translate_EN);
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

Then I want to give later another JSON without any reload of page to en
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Approach - 1 :

inside `app.config` function set translateProvider as below:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
   prefix: 'Scripts/App/resources/_',
   suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
```

When change the language just call :

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('<name of language file>'); 
// say en_US or anything else which is selected.
```

In above code I have assume that name of resource file given as below:

```
Scripts/App/resources/_en_US.json
```

### Approach - 2 :

inside `app.config`

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader');
```

For CustomLoader :

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('customLoader', function ($q, TranslationService) {

    return function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

          deferred.resolve(TranslationService.getLanguages().filter(function(lang){
                return lang.key == options.key
          })[0].values);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

});
```

In `TranslationService`  file:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('TranslationService', function () {
    var languages = [];

    return {
        setLanguages: function (data) {
            languages = data;
        },

        getLanguages: function () {
            return languages;
        }
    }
});
```

I am not sure but I think it works for you in case of dynamic resource.

```
//app.config

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.translations('en',{   // replace with dynamic val from service
      'TITLE': '{{ title }}',
      'SUBTITLE': '{{ subtitle }}',
      'STATIC': 'This is static'
    });
```

let me know which approach is work for you. Happy coding.

Comment: the first one wont work cause i get json from database, and i don't understand clearly how work the second one in my case

Comment: in your case entire resource file (json) comes from database?

Comment: All traduction come from database, and i build variable like a json file.

Comment: + I tried to think your case with the two method :
Method1 Decide lang code using service
Method2 decide resource data using service

Comment: the "translate_EN" var is different after an event, i need to refresh app config to make it work with the new one.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xJVyXCKt

Comment: For this purpose you need to make variable of some service so when response come after new data then automatically translate find latest one Value

Comment: $translateProvider.translations('en', translate_EN); translate_EN Will replace with service variable which contains latest value

Comment: But as he find last value he wont refresh automatically right ?

Comment: yes you need to refresh

Comment: so i set the custom loader as u show me, and when translate_EN value update i refresh from app controller ?

Comment: Yes you are right